# SQL replace all instances of word in a field

Tags: sql, sql-server

Any way to do this?  Replace function only replaces first instance.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you're misinformed. [REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) will replace all occurences, not just the first.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this in a new query:

```
 DECLARE @Phrase varchar(1000)
 SELECT @Phrase = 'az a1 az a3 az a4 az a6'
 SELECT REPLACE(@Phrase, 'az', 'B')
```

This results in your expected/desired behaviour:

```
B a1 B a3 B a4 B a6
```

Answer (score 2):

According to MSDN:

```
Replaces all occurrences of a specified string value with another string value.
```

Try this:

```
DECLARE @x nvarchar(50)
SET @x = 'BobbyBobbyBobby'

SET @x = replace(@x, 'Bobby', '')

PRINT '!' + @x + '!'
```

It will print

```
!!
```

See the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) documentation for more information.